# How to group loop results in wordpress by meta value and show heading for every meta value found

Tags: wordpress, custom-post-type

I'd like to get something like this:

[Frontend results](https://i.stack.imgur.com/T2Us7.png)

I have a CPT called "Property" and every property have a meta value "owner" (HR19 / Other) and i'd like to show them separated by "owner" with a heading like the image attached and I need to paginate them every 9 pages.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: Please show us what have you tried...

Comment: Please read [What topics can I ask about](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) and [ask] a good question and the perfect question and how to [create a Minimal, Complete and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) **SO is not a free** Coding or Code Conversion or Debugging or Tutorial or Library Finding service _**We try to fix your code, we do not write your code**_

Answer (score 0):

What I understand your meta key is "owner", if that is correct meta keys are "HR19" and "Other".

If above info is correct why don't you try to separate both sections by separate queries.

Suppose prepare one section for HR19 and query for that will be,

```
$query = new WP_Query( array( 'meta_key' => 'owner', 'meta_value' = 'hr/19',  'meta_compare' => '=' ) );
```

Write down the loop and after loop use `wp_reset_postdata`. Similarly go for other meta value and write down custom query.

Regarding pagination you can use separate paginations for both section and use ajax to get posts for that particular section.

Here is a nice [post](https://premium.wpmudev.org/blog/load-posts-ajax/) for getting posts via ajax. Hope this helps. If requirement is different then let me know in comments.